# Построение пути категорий php

Tags: php

Привет всем!
Подскажите, плз, кто знает, как сформировать строку пути на сайте, если есть дерево категорий в базе.

Скрин:

[image]

Вызов по id.
Например:
getPath(4);

Должно выводить:
Группа 2 > Группа 2.1

Comment: @15828, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы собрал все категории в ассоциативный массив, и при вызове функции рекурсивно собирать данные о родителях.
Например,
Массив:

> $arr = [
>  'catid'=>['parent_id','name']
> ];

И в функции доставать из массива данные: $arr[$catid]

Answer (score 0):

Это sql-запрос:

```
select c.name as sub_cat, c.id as sub_cat, 
sc.name as parent_name, sc.id as parent_id   
from categories c
left outer  JOIN categories sc ON  sc.id = c.parent_id 
where c.id=4
```

Предположим, что после выполнения запроса мы получим массив вида:

```
   $data = array ( 0 => array( 
     "sub_cat" => "Группа 2.1", "sub_id"=>4,
     "parent_name"=> "Группа 2", "parent_id"=>2 ) 
   );
```

Тогда построение пути выглядит так:

```
echo $data[0]["parent_name"],"-->",$data[0]["sub_name"];
```

На тот случай если нужен третий уровень и глубже - подобную процедуру нужно повторить рекурсивно - с низшего уровня к верхнему

Comment: немного не то, но все равно спасибо

Comment: что именно "не то"?